# Using $match on computed field Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this aggregation query in MongoDB:

```
db.questions.aggregate([
{ $project:{question:1,detail:1, choices:1, answer:1,
  percent_false:{
  $multiply:[100,{$divide:["$answear_false",{$add:["$answear_false","$answear_true"]}]}]},
  percent_true:{
  $multiply:[100,{$divide:["$answear_true",{$add:["$answear_false","$answear_true"]}]}]}    }}, {$match:{status:'active'} } 
]).pretty()
```

I want using $match on 2 computed fields "percent_true" and "percent_false" like this

```
$match : {percent_true:{$gte:20}}
```

How can i do ?

Comment: {$match : {percent_true:{$gte:20}, anotherField:{$lte: 10}, yetAnotherField:12345}}, no?

Comment: Your code block is really hard to read. Can you please put more effort into indenting it more next time?

Answer (score 3):

Singe the aggregation framework works in stages, you can treat the computed fields as if they were normal fields because from the `$match`'s perspective, they are normal.

```
{ $project:{
      question:1,detail:1, choices:1, answer:1,
      percent_false:{
        $multiply:[100,{$divide:["$answear_false",{$add:["$answear_false","$answear_true"]}]}]
      },
      percent_true:{
        $multiply:[100,{$divide:["$answear_true",{$add:["$answear_false","$answear_true"]}]}]}    
    }
}, 
{$match:{
    status:'active',
    percent_true:{$gte:20}
    //When documents get fed to match they already have a percent_true field, so you can match on them as normal
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @David Grinberg :D

Comment: @KhánhĐàm Please upvote and accept if the answer helped you.